# How to place in Swift the AR World Origin into a detected QR-Code at the wall and rotate it?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit

at the moment I use the Vision Framework to recognize QR-Codes at the wall and place an AR Anchor after detection.

I use `setWorldOrigin()` to move the world origin to the recognized anchor at the qr code. This works so far.

My problem is the rotation of the world origin. I want, that the x is directly moving out of the QR-Code and the z is moving in a 90° out to the right side of the QR-Code.

I don't get it, how to rotate it properly, so the rotation is always different depending on the camera view.

Is there a way to work with Plane detection? I implemented it, but I don't understand how to use them to adapt the world origin.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Hi Marcel, Can you put the code snippet. 
You must have configured ARWorldTrackingConfiguration to detect the plane and rotate the object by below snippet. Let's hope it will help you. https://gist.github.com/shrawan2015/a14f3bf560cc1dabfc5def0265302bd5

Comment: @Shrawan    '''    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.isAutoFocusEnabled = true
        configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]
        configuration.isLightEstimationEnabled = true
        configuration.worldAlignment = .gravity''' this is my ar world config. Where do you init the object in your code example?